# Protocol inheritance with associated type

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I have a base protocol that describes the router behavior:

```
protocol BaseRouterProtocol: AnyObject {
    associatedtype View: MainView
    func dismiss(viewController: ViewController<View>?)
}

extension BaseRouterProtocol {
    func dismiss(viewController: ViewController<View>?) {
        viewController?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

I want to adopt this protocol to another like this:

```
protocol StartRouterProtocol: BaseRouterProtocol where View == StartView {
    func showTermsVC()
    func showSignInVC()
}
```

But when I create a variable of this type:

```
let router: StartRouterProtocol
```

Compiler throws me an error:

> Protocol 'StartRouterProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Why does this happening if I have described the type that I expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a protocol has an associated type, that protocol can't be used as a type by itself for instance declarations-- only for generic constraints and declaring conformance.

So in this case, Swift is saying "yeah, but what is the concrete type for `StartRouterProtocol`'s associated type?"

In this case, it's asking you to either:

1. Use a concrete type directly, i.e. `let router: MyStartViewClass` with this ***conformance declaration***, elsewhere: `class MyStartViewClass: StartRouterProtocol { ... }`)
2. OR, push the need for a concrete type up one layer, as a ***generic constraint*** i.e.

```
class MyRouterController<T: StartRouterProtocol> {
    let router: T
}
```

This is probably not what you were hoping for, but unfortunately associated types add complexity to how you use protocols, especially if you're familiar with generics & interfaces from other languages. (i.e. Java/C# interfaces)

You can work around some aspects of associated types by using a concept called "type erasure" -- but that can cause other problems and complexity.

Here's some further reading that may help: https://medium.com/monstar-lab-bangladesh-engineering/swift-from-protocol-to-associatedtype-then-type-erasure-a4093f6a2d08